# How can I build GDAL without the static libraries?

Tags: gdal, configuration, build

#### Background

I'm building GDAL myself, because I need it linked against libkml, with:

```
wget -O gdal.tar.gz "https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/archive/${GDAL_VERSION}.tar.gz"
tar --extract --file gdal.tar.gz --strip-components 1
cd gdal
./configure --prefix=/my/install/dir --with-libkml=/where/libkml/is
make
make install
```

However, the build on my hosting provider (heroku) is time-critical - on the borderline where sometimes it times out, sometimes not. If I could accelerate the hour-long build by even 10 minutes, that'd solve my issue.

#### The goal

I believe I don't need the static library `libgdal.a`as well as the `.so` which is what I use (for geodjango). If I don't need it, I don't have to build it. You see where this is going...

#### The question

What configure option, if  any, would avoid building the unneeded static version of GDAL and instead build only the dynamic verison?

Answer (score 1):

OK, figured it out (by googling for the opposite!). [This issue](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1070) happens to be trying the opposite (building static only) so gave me a clue.

Adding the `--disable-static` flag when calling `./configure` prevents generation of the static libraries, shaving a few minutes off my build time. The build command is now:

```
./configure --disable-static --prefix=/my/install/dir --with-libkml=/where/libkml/is
```

The opposite would be `--disable-shared` to build static only.